# What was the relation of Urahara's Bankai's name with its ability?

Tags: bleach, japanese-language

Urahara Kisuke's Bankai is "Kannonbiraki Benihime Aratame", which means **Modification of The Crimson Princess' Dissection at the Doors of Avalokiteśvara**.

Does the name have any meaning/significance to its ability to dissect and restructure virtually anything (either organic or inorganic)?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Wikipedia

> Avalokiteśvara is a bodhisattva who embodies the compassion of **all** Buddhas. This bodhisattva is **variably depicted**, described and is portrayed in different cultures as either female or male.

Thus, the Avalokiteśvara part in its name relates to the Bankai's ability to restructure everything into anything.

The key here are the words bolded above. Avalokiteśvara or Kanon, as I would refer to her from this point on, was known in many-many form. But all of those forms are her.

Things have different appearances, called by different names, but they are all formed of atoms, of matter. From the most simple to the most complicated, they are in core are made of matter.

The bankai's ability is to restructure the matter so that one thing becomes another thing. Or if we are to use Kanon, from one appearance of Kanon to another.